# How I automate my python script or get multiple entries in one run?

Tags: python

I am running the following python script:

```python
import random

result_str = ''.join((random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()') for i in range(8)))
with open('file_output.txt','a') as out:
    out.write(f'{result_str}\n')
```

Is there a way I could automate this script to run automatically? or If I can get multiple outputs instantly?
Ex. Right now the output stores itself in the file one by one
kmfd5s6s

But if somehow I can get 1,000,000 entries in the file on one click and there is no duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest your `out.write()` in a loop, something like this, to make it happen multiple times:

```py
import random

with open('file_output.txt','a') as out:
    for x in range(1000): # the number of lines you want in the output file
        result_str = ''.join((random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()') for i in range(8)))
        out.write(f'{result_str}\n')
```

However, while unlikely, it is possible that you could end up with duplicate rows. To avoid this, you can generate and store your random strings in a loop and check for duplicates as you go. Once you have enough, write them all to the file outside the loop:

```py
import random

results = []
while len(results) < 1000: # the number of lines you want in the output file
    result_str = ''.join((random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()') for i in range(8)))
    if result_str not in results: # check if the generated result_str is a duplicate
        results.append(result_str)

with open('file_output.txt','a') as out:
    out.write( '\n'.join(results) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Same logic as given by PangolinPaws,but since you require it for a 1,000,000 entries, which is quite large, using `numpy` could be more effecient. Also, replacing `random.choice()` with `random.choices()` with k=8, inorder to avoid the for loop to generate the string.

```
import random
import numpy as np

a = np.array([])
for i in range(1000000):
     str = ''.join((random.choices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()', k = 8)))
    
     if str not in a:
        a = np.append(a,str)
np.savetxt("generate_strings.csv", a, fmt='%s')
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of random.choices(), that's going to come in handy!

Comment: An error has occurred while running the file:

if str not in a:
                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: thats just an indentation error, probably the ```if``` condition line.Updated.